# changing color of the keywords of given sentence

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of keywords of given sentence. So far I have this:

```js
const engSample = document.querySelector(".eng-sample");

engSample.innerHTML = getColoredEngSample("I have been walking");

function getColoredEngSample(text) {

        let result;
        const keywords = ["have", "has", "been", "ing"];
        keywords.forEach(key => {
            result = text.replace(key, `<span class='bold-sample'>${key}</span>`);
        });
    return result;
}
```

```css
.bold-sample { color: #ff3c00; }
```

```html
<p class="eng-sample"></p>
```

As you see only `ing` color changes and the rest of keywords not.

How can I fix this or achieve the same result using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing `result` with original `text` on every iteration. So you should change your code to be:

```
function getColoredEngSample(text) {
    let result = text;
    const keywords = ["have", "has", "been", "ing"];
    keywords.forEach(key => {
        result = result.replace(key, `<span class='bold-sample'>${key}</span>`);
    });

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use your variable `text` which doesnt change over time. Every time your loop starts a round it will use the same text from your parameter `text`. On the next run of the loop the text-change is written to result but never used again. So result will only contain the result of the last loop pass.

```js
const engSample = document.querySelector(".eng-sample");

engSample.innerHTML = getColoredEngSample("I have been walking");

function getColoredEngSample(text) {

        let result = text;
        const keywords = ["have", "has", "been", "ing"];
        keywords.forEach(key => {
            result = result.replace(key, `<span class='bold-sample'>${key}</span>`);
        });
    return result;
}
```

```css
.bold-sample { color: #ff3c00; }
```

```html
<p class="eng-sample"></p>
```